# ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (6,) and (6, 15, 15)

Tags: python, data-science, linear-regression, sgd

## assignment:Implement SGD Classifier with Logloss and L2 regularization Using SGD without using sklearn

```
<p><pre>Initialize the weight_vector and intercept term to zeros (Write your code in def initialize_weights())

Create a loss function (Write your code in def logloss())

logloss=−1∗1nΣforeachYt,Ypred(Ytlog10(Ypred)+(1−Yt)log10(1−Ypred))

for each epoch:

    for each batch of data points in train: (keep batch size=1)

        calculate the gradient of loss function w.r.t each weight in weight vector (write your code in def gradient_dw())

        dw(t)=xn(yn−σ((w(t))Txn+bt))−λNw(t))

        Calculate the gradient of the intercept (write your code in def gradient_db()) check this

        db(t)=yn−σ((w(t))Txn+bt))

        Update weights and intercept (check the equation number 32 in the above mentioned pdf):
        w(t+1)←w(t)+α(dw(t))

        b(t+1)←b(t)+α(db(t))

    calculate the log loss for train and test with the updated weights (you can check the python assignment 10th question)

    And if you wish, you can compare the previous loss and the current loss, if it is not updating, then you can stop the training

    append this loss in the list ( this will be used to see how loss is changing for each epoch after the training is over )</pre></p>
```

importing libraries

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
  from sklearn import linear_model
```

Creating custom dataset

```
    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50000, n_features=15, n_informative=10, n_redundant=5,
                               n_classes=2, weights=[0.7], class_sep=0.7, random_state=15)
```

Splitting data into train and test

```
    # you need not standardize the data as it is already standardized
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=15)



    def initialize_weights(row_vector):
        ''' In this function, we will initialize our weights and bias'''
        #initialize the weights as 1d array consisting of all zeros similar to the dimensions of row_vector
        #you use zeros_like function to initialize zero, check this link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html
        #initialize bias to zero
        w = np.zeros_like(X_train[0])
        b=0
        return w,b
    dim=X_train[0] 
    w,b = initialize_weights(dim)
    print('w =',(w))
    print('b =',str(b))
    def sigmoid(z):
        ''' In this function, we will return sigmoid of z'''
        # compute sigmoid(z) and return
        return 1 /(1+np.exp(-z))
    def logloss(y_true,y_pred):
        # you have been given two arrays y_true and y_pred and you have to calculate the logloss
        #while dealing with numpy arrays you can use vectorized operations for quicker calculations as compared to using loops
        #https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html
        #https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorized-operations-in-numpy/
        #write your code here
        
        sum=0
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
             sum += (y_true[i] * np.log10(y_pred[i])) + ((1 - y_true[i]) * np.log10(1 - y_pred[i]))
        loss = -1 * (1 / len(y_true)) * sum
         
        return loss
    #make sure that the sigmoid function returns a scalar value, you can use dot function operation
    def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
        '''In this function, we will compute the gardient w.r.to w '''
        dw = x * (y - sigmoid(np.dot(w,x) + b) - (alpha / N) * w)
        
        return dw
    #sb should be a scalar value
    def gradient_db(x,y,w,b):
         '''In this function, we will compute gradient w.r.to b '''
         db = y - sigmoid(np.dot(w,x)+ b)  
         
         return db
    # prediction function used to compute predicted_y given the dataset X
    def pred(w,b, X):
        N = len(X)
        predict = []
        for i in range(N):
            z=np.dot(w,X[i])+b
            predict.append(sigmoid(z))
        return np.array(predict)
    def train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0):
      
        ''' In this function, we will implement logistic regression'''
        #Here eta0 is learning rate
        #implement the code as follows
        
        # for every epoch
            # for every data point(X_train,y_train)
               #compute gradient w.r.to w (call the gradient_dw() function)
               #compute gradient w.r.to b (call the gradient_db() function)
               #update w, b
            # predict the output of x_train [for all data points in X_train] using pred function with updated weights
            #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
            # store all the train loss values in a list
            # predict the output of x_test [for all data points in X_test] using pred function with updated weights
            #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
            # store all the test loss values in a list
            # you can also compare previous loss and current loss, if loss is not updating then stop the process 
            # you have to return w,b , train_loss and test loss
            
        train_loss = []
        test_loss = []
      
        # initalize the weights (call the initialize_weights(X_train[0]) function)
        w,b = initialize_weights(X_train[0]) # Initialize the weights
        #write your code to perform SGD
        # for every epoch
        for i in range(epochs):
            
            train_pred = []
            test_pred = []
            # for every data point(X_train,y_train)
            for j in range(N):
              #compute gradient w.r.to w (call the gradient_dw() function)
              dw= gradient_dw(X_train[j],y_train[j],w,b,alpha,N)
              
              #compute gradient w.r.to b (call the gradient_db() function)
              db = gradient_db(X_train[j],y_train[j],w,b)
              
              #update w, b
              w= w+ (eta0* dw)
              b =b+ (eta0* db)
    
    #predict the output of x_train [for all data points in X_train] using pred function with updated weights
    
            for k in range(0,N):
                
                w1_predict = pred(w,b,X_train[k])
                train_pred.append(w1_predict)
    ##compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
            loss_pred1 = logloss(y_train,train_pred)
            train_loss.append(loss_pred1)
    # predict the output of x_test [for all data points in X_test] using pred function with updated weights
            for k in range(len(X_test)):
                
                w2_predict = pred(w,b,X_test[k])
                test_pred.append(w2_predict)
    #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)        
            loss_pred2 = logloss(y_test,test_pred)
            test_loss.append(loss_pred2)
    
        return w,b,train_loss,test_loss
    alpha=0.001
    eta0=0.001
    N=len(X_train)
    epochs=6
    w,b,train_loss,test_loss=train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0)

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    epoch = [i for i in range(1,epochs+1,1)]
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(epoch,train_loss , label='train log loss')
    plt.plot(epoch,test_loss, label='test log loss')
    plt.xlabel("epoch number")
    plt.ylabel("log loss")
    plt.title("log loss curve of logistic regression")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show
```

I am getting this below error. I used grader function check all the function, its coming true. However. I am getting an below error while running the code. I tried use reshape to change the shape of train loss. still getting the error. Please help

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    
    <ipython-input-28-52c352e46321> in <module>()
          1 plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
          2 plt.grid()
    ----> 3 plt.plot(epoch,train_loss , label='train log loss')
          4 plt.plot(epoch,test_loss, label='test log loss')
          5 plt.xlabel("epoch number")
    
    3 frames
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
        340 
        341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    --> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
        343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
        344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (1350,)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (6,) and (6, 15, 15). This is the error i am getting.